# How to update database to empty?

Tags: javascript, mysql, puppeteer

Im trying some scraping off a website and i need to scrape the number of comments and the earliest comment date. However, when there is no comment, it will return as the date and time that i scraped which appears in the database too. But what i wanted was that since there is no comments, the earliest date field should be empty. Is there anything wrong with my codes? Really appreciate for help, had been trying for a week. Thank you!

```
// go to comment area
await page.waitForSelector("div.ivu-table-wrapper");
await page.waitFor(3000);

// get number of comments
const noOfComments = await page.$eval("#app-comment > div.comment-details > div:nth-child(4) > p", p => p.innerText.slice(16,-3));

// get the number of li 
let len = await page.$$eval(".comment-details .ivu-page-item", e => {
    return e.length;
});

// if there is only 2 pages 
if (len == 2) {
    len -= 1;
}
else if (len == 1) {
    len -= 1;
}

// click on the last page (eg: len = 4, 4+2)
await page.click(".comment-details .ivu-page-item:nth-child(" + (len + 2) + ") > a").catch(async (err) => {
    await page.click(".comment-details .ivu-page-item:nth-child(" + (len + 1) + ") > a");
});

await page.waitFor(7000);

// get the earliest comment date
const dates = await page.$eval("div.ivu-table-body > table > tbody > tr:last-child > td:nth-child(3)", td => td.innerText.trim()).catch(async (err) => {
    console.log("");
});                 
const eDate = moment(dates).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

console.log("Rank: ", count); //int
console.log("Name: ", name); //string
console.log("Release Date: ", relDate); //date
console.log("Developer: ", developer); //string
console.log("Rating: ", rating); //float
console.log("Size: ", storage); //float
console.log("No. of Comments: ", noOfComments); //int
console.log("Earliest date: ", eDate); //datetime
console.log("Scrape date: ", today); //date
console.log("\n");

const data_values = [count, name, relDate, developer, rating, storage, noOfComments, eDate, today];
console.log(data_values);

connection.connect(function(err) {
   var sql = "INSERT INTO Qimai_BS (ranking, name, release_date, developer, rating, storage_size, no_of_comments, earliest_date, scrape_date) VALUES ?";
   var values = [data_values];
   connection.query(sql, [values], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Rows Inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`dates` will be undefined when your script cannot find a date. The problem therefore is in the following line:

```js
const eDate = moment(dates).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

When you call `moment()` without arguments (or `undefined` as argument) it will take the current date instead. So what you need to do is check first if `dates` is set, example:

```js
const eDate = (!dates) ? null : moment(dates).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Comment: can i also ask if i can move move a browser position in Puppeteer?

Comment: @KohShuanJin You mean to move the browser window in non-headless mode? I don't think that is possible. If my answer helped you, you might want to [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) by clicking the big checkbox next to it. :)

Comment: is there a way to move a browser position? then what does page.mouse.move do?